# android:out of memorry in jelly bean (4.1)

Tags: android

I am facing a problem that a application runs nice under android devices whoes version is less than 4.1,but a device of version 4.1  or upper  throws out of memory exception.

I use a ListView putting some ImageViews loaded from APK resource,ImageView.setImageResrouce(id);

When a item clicked in ListView ,it popup a GridView containing some ImageViews just like ListView I used.

On lower version devices ,it works,but not a upper version device including version 4.1.

Comment: post your code and logcat trace :)

Comment: I fixed it.This problem is caused by too many big images with a resolution 400x600.haha @AndroidLearner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.This problem is caused by too many big images with a resolution 400x600.haha